# Ensure deletion of user data from firebase database and mysql when user is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase

I use firebase for authentication and realtime database. I added rails + mysql as backend to do heavy liftings.

Both databases have user data, which must be deleted when user deletes their accounts.

I would like to know common ways to ensure deletion of user data from firebase database and rails+mysql when user is deleted in firebase.

Is is possible to implement transaction like mechanism?

Comment: Cloud functions might be helpful, add a function to listen to user deletion, than call your api to delete data from database. Take note: cloud functions is not free to send external requests. You have to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is currently possible via Firebase Ruby APIs out there. Even the REST API, I think its not possible... :=/